# Why to have private field for simplest singleton implementation?

Tags: c#, singleton

In the first version of the implementation in Jon Skeet implementation [here](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton), he has the following code:

```cs
// Bad code! Do not use!
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Singleton();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering why not just make it:

```cs
public sealed class Singleton
{
  private Singleton() {}
  public static Singleton Instance = new Singleton();
}
```

What are the differences between the two snippets ?

(I'm aware that using `Lazy<T>` is much better solution)

Comment: This would also work; `public static Singleton Instance { get; }= new Singleton();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example could be set via external code:

```
Singleton.Instance = null;
```

The first could not, because it doesn't have a public setter.

The other difference is that the property enables lazy initialisation i.e. the `Singleton` is only instantited when the property is first accessed, whereas the static field would cause the instance to be created as soon as the program starts running.

Comment: REALLY great point. I thought it can't be set because it needs to set to object of type `Singleton` which has no public constructor. But forgot about setting to `null`.

Comment: I guess, this should be "The _first_ could not, because it doesn't have a public setter."

Comment: But just adding  `readonly` behind static would solve this problem. And it would save to test `instance != null`on each access. But Fields are a No-Go for some people.

Comment: @holger yes true. The other difference would be that the property would enable lazy initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of Singleton is to **prevent** the ability to instantiate a class more than once (or to **avoid** having multiple instances of the singelton), and if you use the second snippet other classes will always have the ability to set the singleton class' instance again:

```
Singleton.Instance = new Singleton();
```

**UPDATE:**

I didn't notice that the constructor is private then we cannot set it this way. Anyway as @JohnathanBarclay has mentioned in his answer that the class can be reset to null and you will never be able to set it again.

Comment: That code would not compile. `Singleton` has a private constructor.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay My mistake, I've updated the answer